# Can I compare two arbitrary references in a way that can be used in a CompareTo method?

Tags: c#

I'm writing an implementation of `IComparable<T>.CompareTo(T)` for a struct. I'm doing a member-wise comparison (i.e. `d = a.CompareTo(other.a); if (d != 0) { return d; }` etc.), but one of the members is of a class (let's call it `Y`) that doesn't implement `IComparable` or have any other reasonable way of comparing so I just want to compare the references (in this case I know that all instances of `Y` are unique). Is there a way of doing that that will yield an `int` that is suitable for use in a comparison method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comparing the results of [`Object.GetHashCode()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx) works well enough for my purposes (I just care about reference equality and it doesn't matter where anything unequal is sorted. I want  instances of `T` that have the same instances of `Y` as members to be next to each other in the sorted result). My `T.CompareTo()` uses the following helper:

```
    static int Compare(object a, object b)
    {
        if (a == null)
        {
            return b == null ? 0 : 1;
        }
        if (b == null)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        return a.GetHashCode().CompareTo(b.GetHashCode());
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not meaningful to compare references looking for order relationships. It's only meaningful to look for equality.

Comment: I was planning to retort with something like, "but we all know they're just pointers really under the covers, and you can sort of an array of references", but I just tried and apparently you can't sort an array of arbitrary references so I guess the underlying pointer is well and truly hidden. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your statement that the class

> doesn't implement IComparable or have
>   any other reasonable way of comparing

Seems to be contra-indicative of finding

> a way of doing that that will yield an
>   int that is suitable for use in a
>   comparison method

If the objects cannot be reasonably compared for ordering, it is best to exclude them from the comparison logic entirely.